# resize images for cordova mobile application based on detected device

Tags: html, cordova

I'v built a cordova mobile application which i intend to deploy for several platforms. The problem i'm facing is images and thumbnails within the app. how to make the application detect which device is being used and based on that resize all images thumbnails and background (not only icon and splash screen) inside the application to be displayed properly?

I'v read about how this is done for native apps but if i'm gonna follow the same approach for example in android declaring a res folder for different sizes, how can i access them in my html file and pick the right size for the right mobile device? i want this to be tested in emulator how can i automate the process?

take it easy on me it's my first app :)

Comment: You can use responsive css. Through that you can manage for multiple devices.

Comment: i saw that approach but correct me if i'm wrong, i have to declare each and every dimension for each device i want to detect using css queries which is tedious, am i right?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know more about responsive css. I think you should search on Google for that. You will surely get some stuff.

Comment: you define a size of picture for a range of screen size and then add media queries in your css to define which picture to use for which range.